# For how long are moderators elected?

Tags: support, election

I just had a look at the [election page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election), and noticed that multiple candidates that were nominating themselves for moderation already are mods.

They stated,

> [they]'d like to continue as a moderator [...]

This made me wonder. I also visited and voted on the 2016 elections over at StackOverflow, but could not recall any of the nominees already being moderators.

I had a look, but could neither find any information on the [meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/2016-community-moderator-election), nor the [official page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election) and even searching on meta. So my question remains:

**For how long are Worldbuilding moderators elected?**

Am I just missing something? Is this different to how moderation on StackOverflow works? I could imagine so, as the workload there is much bigger than on your beloved Worldbuilding site, I guess.

Can someone point me to some information, or tell me what I missed? I am just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the very most part, *community elected* moderators retain their position until they choose to resign.

Moderators can also be removed by Stack Exchange company officials in the event of serious infractions, violations of the terms of service, etc. This happens, but very rarely.

Pro tempore ("pro tem") moderators are [appointed by Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/29) company officials and keep their positions until they resign, are removed, or until the first community moderator election (which in our case is [now underway](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1)). Pro tem mods are appointed to guide the site through the beta period only, up through graduation and until the community is mature enough to support community moderator elections.

Hence, **any current pro tem mod** (because even with [the input from the community](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/29), there was never any election) who wishes to continue must run in the community moderator election and be elected moderator by the members of the community.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation! If there is any source for that, could you link it?

Comment: @T3H40 I added some links; let me know if you feel those don't address your concerns.

Comment: Already read this post, but missed this paragraph completely: *Soon after the site launches into "public beta," the Community Team will appoint provisional moderators from this community until the community is ready to hold its own elections (once it graduates from beta).* Thanks for pointing it out again.

Comment: It's important to note that I got "elected" to pro tem moderator with 19 votes. I expect we'll see rather more votes than that this time around for every candidate let alone the winning candidates!:D (Elected in quotes since it wasn't an election, those votes were just used by the CM to inform their selection of pro tem moderators).

Comment: Best of luck (to all of you)! :)

Comment: @T3H40 Just remember to vote!

Comment: Don't worry! I will

Comment: Further question on the answer: so we won't have another election until/unless one of the mods we elect now resigns or is otherwise removed? And then it would be an election for just one position?

Comment: @Jerenda I don't know. Sites do grow and sometimes need additional moderators, for example. Maybe the best option is to ask that question of yours as a separate question; that way, someone actually working for Stack Exchange has a much better chance of spotting it, and being able to give more of an actual answer.